# Why do I not see a text box to add a menu item to a menustrip

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: No text box for adding items to menustrip]

I assume this is something simple I've missed.  But every example for adding a menu strip shows a quick and easy design time text box you can type your menu item into.  Then you can click on it and get it's events to add a method.  I get none of that.  I can click on the properties and go to the items collections and add more drop down menus or separators but that's it.  I can never get to an event except for the single click event for the whole menu object itself.  All the examples I've seen say you can just drag a button onto the menu strip.  That doesn't work for me either.  I am using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I myself am baffled by what you show.  I am 100% unable to repro your screen.

Comment: That's weird.  How did you get the menustrip on the form.  I just tried it with VS2019 (v16.7.2).  I opened a form and then double-clicked "MenuStrip" in the toolbox and got th experience you were expecting.  Try selecting the MenuStrip control, then going to the properties tool (right-click, Properties) and adding things to the "Items" property.  It's not as cool as the full designer, but it works

Comment: I have v16.7.7  and I'm using community edition.  But certainly that wouldn't cause the issue.

Comment: Did that and same issue.  I will also try on another machine I have VS installed on and maybe try a full reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  It's a difference between .Net Core and .Net Framework.  If you create a Framework project you get the text box to add your items.  If you do Core you do not.

Comment: Does using the `Items` property (in `Properties`) work?